# Bounded open sets with same boundaries

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $U_1$, $U_2$ two bounded open subsets of the euclidean plane.
and denote by $\partial U_1$ and $\partial U_2$ their topological boundaries.
Does $\partial U_1 = \partial U_2$ implies $U_1 = U_2$?

This is not true without further hypothesis.
An example of two disjoint bounded open sets with same
boundaries is obtained by considering a curve separating the
interior of the closed unit disk and spiraling to its boundary.

[image: two open sets with same boundary]

I am looking for a condition on the boundary $\partial U_1$
that insures that there are no bounded open sets other than
$U_1$ with the same boundary than $U_1$.
Does local path connectedness of $\partial U_1$ suffice?

Comment: If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are both additionally connected, then I think the answer is yes. Clearly both have simply connected interiors, so they are Jordan domains by [Moore, 1918]. So one is not bounded by JCT.

Comment: @Salo Why should they be Jordan domains? There could be cut points on the boundary.  Think of a circle with an interval pointing inward.

Comment: I agree that if the boundary is a Jordan curve, then the answer is yes, just by mapping by a global homeomorphism the curve to a circle. Then it is easy to see that the only bounded open set with boundary the unit circle is the unit disk.

Comment: I missed that in Moore, you assume "uniform connectedness im kleinen"; the open disk minus an interval is simply connected, i.e. "connected im kleinen", but not uniformly so. (Seems like a very naive confusion now.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakes_of_Wada

Comment: @Brian Lakes of Wada don't have a locally connected boundary. So, I don't think it really helps.

Comment: @coudy: It wasn't meant as an answer to the question. But I thought you might appreciate reading about the Lakes of Wada if you're not already familiar -- it's very much in the same ballpark as your question, anyway.

Comment: Local (path) connectedness of the boundary does not suffice: you can easily find two open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ whose boundary is the Sierpinski Triangle $T$ (or e.g. the Sierpinski Carpet). For the definition of $U_1$ and $U_2$ you just need to consider all the bounded complementary domains of T and divide them by induction into two groups in such a way that in each group you have arbitrarily close sets to any point of $T$ finally. Note that neither $U_1$, nor $U_2$ is connected.

Comment: @Vejnar Indeed, thanks for your nice counterexample to local connectedness. Now I am wondering if locally contractible is a sufficient hypothesis.

Comment: I guess that the assumption of local contractibility of the boundary is still not enough. Just consider a topological graph $G$ with two vertices and four edges between the two vertices. Consider $G$ embedded in the plane. Now, there are three bounded complementary domains - say $A, B, C$ ("from the left to the right"). Let $U_1=A\cup C$, $U_2=A\cup B\cup C$. I suspect that you need to assume some sort of connectedness of $U_1$ and $U_2$ to get a positive answer.